# pythonでLDA

Tags: python, 自然言語処理

以下のコードを実行するとエラーが表示されてしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
 */usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:402: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' %
```

**実行したコード**

```
from gensim import models

lda_model = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=10, alpha='symmetric', random_state=0)

lda_model.save('lda.model')
```

Comment: 参考までに、gensim 3.8.1 では上記の問題の対応がなされていてワーニングメッセージは表示されません。

Comment: ローカルではなくWeb環境で実行したところ問題なくできました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 問題が解決した場合には、些細な情報でも構いませんのでぜひ個別の「回答」として投稿してください (コメントはあくまで補足情報などをやり取りするための手段です)。

Answer (score 0):

ローカルではなくWeb環境で実行したところ問題なくできました。ありがとうございました。